# How to retrieve all variables using the Grakn Python driver

Tags: python, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I want to get all the variables in my query using the Grakn Python Client. This is my query:

```
match $p isa person; 
$f isa family; 
$r ($p, $f); 
get;
```

I am using this code from the documentation:

```
answer_iterator = read_transaction.query(read_query)
for answer in answer_iterator:
    ans = answer.map().get("x")
    print("Retrieved ans with id " + ans.id)
```

However, when I run this I get this error:

```
    print("Retrieved ans with id " + ans.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id
```

Is it possible to retrieve all variables in my query without having to specify them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and in fact you already did! `answer.map()` is a python dictionary with variable names as keys (strings) and concept objects as the values. (Docs [here](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python#retrieve-a-mapping-of-variables-to-concepts).)

Therefore, to print the ids of all concepts (using f-strings from Python 3.6+):

```py
for answer in answer_iterator:
    ans_dict = answer.map()
    for var, concept in ans_dict.items():
        print(f"Retrieved ans for variable {var} with id {concept.id}")
```